# Book series about a young man who apprentices with a magician in a castle

Tags: story-identification, novel

I have only read the one book. I believe it was called *The Apprentice* or something similar.

It is a very popular series with a lot of books.

The one I read was about a young man who left his home to study with a famous magician. He lived in what I think was an old castle or something with a large tower.

A few things more details I remember: He had to clean out the library, the place was haunted (he would see people or scenes from another time and they rode on falcons and fought orcs.)

The magician was friends with a king. The orc scene I'm recalling was when they were flying on the back of the falcon, or some large bird im remembering as a falcon, over a marsh type land one of the birds was shot down in some way orcs started coming out of what I'm trying to remember think was a woodsy area and the apprentice had just learned some magic was using to keep them away and another large orc who could actually do magic came out and the magician showed up just in time to save the apprentice.

Comment: At the end of the book, did the Head Wizard tell him that he's fired?

Comment: Lol. Maybe one of these; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=the+apprentice&type=Fiction+Titles

Comment: Lol sounds like something he would have said to him but I never got to the end I'm trying to remember the book so I can finish it

Comment: When did you read this book?

Answer (score 3):

Possibly this is [***Magician: Apprentice***](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13812.Magician?from_search=true) by Raymond E. Feist, the first book in the (extensive) [Riftwar saga](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40473-the-riftwar-saga). This is a long and well known series of books. The boy does indeed leave his home to learn magic at the hands of an older wizard. There are orcs and ghosts but I can't recall anyone riding on a falcon.

[image: cover of "Magician: Apprentice" by Raymond E. Feist]

Comment: If this the correct answer, Katie, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: Nope. Definitely not. Having read this book, it nowhere *near* matches the OP's description. The magician isn't "famous", and there's no library cleaning, falcon riding, or orc fighting. Sorry, but -1.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I seem to recall that orcs come out of the rift. Also Pug is taught by the Magician Kulgan who seems pretty well known

Comment: Kulgan is the magician of the local castle. He's not "famous" in any larger sense than that, at least until later due to his association with Milamber. And Tsurani aren't orcs (!) - the closest you've got to orcs in this series are the moredhel or dark elves.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Possibly OP is confusing two properties. Either way, it's worth seeing if this is the right answer. It seems the obvious choice, but then there's a great big pile of books called "*something* apprentice" in the fantasy category.

Comment: I read this years ago. I've read different ideas on how to read the whole series like what order to read the books in because they are all the same story but different times and characters.

Comment: The magician was friends with a king. The orc scene I'm recalling was when they were flying on the back of the falcon, or some large bird im remembering as a falcon, over a marsh type land one of the birds was shot down in some way orcs started coming out of what I'm trying to remember think was a woodsy area and the apprentice had just learned some magic was using to keep them away and another large orc who could actually do magic came out and the magician showed up just in time to save the apprentice.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - To be fair, Pug and Tomas do ride dragons, Tomas (in memory) rides giant eagles, they do get assaulted by the freed Tiger men of Draken-Korin(?). It's a big stretch, but not a giant one.